# TypeError: 'LocalFileOpener' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, modin, fsspec

I have a huge dataset with millions of entries (It is a normal .csv file and I get no errors when I load it with pandas). Pandas struggles when trying to load the dataset (.csv), so I decided to use modin, which apparently allows you to use multiple processes with only one line difference. When I run:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-03696c0c8326> in <module>
----> 1 train_df = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
      2 train_df

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\logging\logger_function.py in run_and_log(*args, **kwargs)
     63             """
     64             if LogMode.get() == "disable":
---> 65                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     66 
     67             logger = get_logger()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\pandas\io.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    138     _, _, _, f_locals = inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())
    139     kwargs = {k: v for k, v in f_locals.items() if k in _pd_read_csv_signature}
--> 140     return _read(**kwargs)
    141 
    142 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\pandas\io.py in _read(**kwargs)
     59 
     60     squeeze = kwargs.pop("squeeze", False)
---> 61     pd_obj = FactoryDispatcher.read_csv(**kwargs)
     62     # This happens when `read_csv` returns a TextFileReader object for iterating through
     63     if isinstance(pd_obj, pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\core\execution\dispatching\factories\dispatcher.py in read_csv(cls, **kwargs)
    183     @_inherit_docstrings(factories.BaseFactory._read_csv)
    184     def read_csv(cls, **kwargs):
--> 185         return cls.__factory._read_csv(**kwargs)
    186 
    187     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\core\execution\dispatching\factories\factories.py in _read_csv(cls, **kwargs)
    215     )
    216     def _read_csv(cls, **kwargs):
--> 217         return cls.io_cls.read_csv(**kwargs)
    218 
    219     @classmethod

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\logging\logger_function.py in run_and_log(*args, **kwargs)
     63             """
     64             if LogMode.get() == "disable":
---> 65                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     66 
     67             logger = get_logger()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\core\io\file_dispatcher.py in read(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    151         postprocessing work on the resulting query_compiler object.
    152         """
--> 153         query_compiler = cls._read(*args, **kwargs)
    154         # TODO (devin-petersohn): Make this section more general for non-pandas kernel
    155         # implementations.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\logging\logger_function.py in run_and_log(*args, **kwargs)
     63             """
     64             if LogMode.get() == "disable":
---> 65                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     66 
     67             logger = get_logger()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\core\io\text\text_file_dispatcher.py in _read(cls, filepath_or_buffer, **kwargs)
   1053             )
   1054             f.seek(old_pos)
-> 1055             splits = cls.partitioned_file(
   1056                 f,
   1057                 num_partitions=NPartitions.get(),

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\logging\logger_function.py in run_and_log(*args, **kwargs)
     63             """
     64             if LogMode.get() == "disable":
---> 65                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     66 
     67             logger = get_logger()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\core\io\text\text_file_dispatcher.py in partitioned_file(cls, f, num_partitions, nrows, skiprows, quotechar, is_quoting, encoding, newline, header_size, pre_reading)
    270         file_size = cls.file_size(f)
    271 
--> 272         rows_skipper(header_size)
    273 
    274         if pre_reading:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\core\io\text\text_file_dispatcher.py in skipper(n)
    496                 return 0
    497             else:
--> 498                 return cls._read_rows(
    499                     f,
    500                     quotechar=quotechar,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\logging\logger_function.py in run_and_log(*args, **kwargs)
     63             """
     64             if LogMode.get() == "disable":
---> 65                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     66 
     67             logger = get_logger()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modin\core\io\text\text_file_dispatcher.py in _read_rows(cls, f, nrows, quotechar, is_quoting, outside_quotes, encoding, newline)
    392             iterator = f
    393 
--> 394         for line in iterator:
    395             if is_quoting and line.count(quotechar) % 2:
    396                 outside_quotes = not outside_quotes

TypeError: 'LocalFileOpener' object is not iterable
```

Here is the full code:

```
import modin.pandas as pd
train_df = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
```

From my research this apparently has something to do with the fsspec versions (from what I could understand)

I get the same error when I run this code:

```
import fsspec

file_path = r"./train_data.csv"
file = fsspec.open(file_path).open()

for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-3fc27fe187bb> in <module>
      4 file = fsspec.open(file_path).open()
      5 
----> 6 for line in file:
      7     print(line)

TypeError: 'LocalFileOpener' object is not iterable
```

Some version information:

```
fsspec version: 0.7.4
modin version: 0.15.2
Windows version: 11
Python version: 3.8.3
```

Can someone help me what the problem here is and how I can solve it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See https://github.com/fsspec/filesystem_spec/blob/master/fsspec/implementations/local.py#L354 : LocalFileObject *is* iterable and has been for quite some time. You will need to do some local debug to find out why this isn't picked up for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following environment works for me with a sample csv dataset:

```yaml
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- python=3.9
- fsspec=2022.7.1
- modin=0.15.2
```

The `fsspec` you have is rather old.

Comment: I tried to pip install with the same fsspec and modin versions as yours, but it still didn't work. I read somewhere, that it has something to do with Windows 11, but I am not sure of the details. "pip install fsspec==2022.7.1" and "pip install modin==0.15.2"

Comment: ah, i'm on macos